# Node.js install errror Can not find module ../json/parser

Tags: node.js, express

I am installing an legacy project of node working on 0.10.25, When i run npm install its throeing error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '../json/parser'
```

And the error is in following

```
node_modules\nodemailer\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\aws.js:1:73
```

Any clue wphat should I debug for or what package is missing, I matched from server environment and installed all.

On Server machine is Ubuntu, while I am trying install on Winwows.

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file in your project with the json parser api registered?

Comment: No its is not present this is the problem, it is inbuilt module why package should miss.

Comment: paste your server code please.

Comment: If it's inbuilt, then simple call it like `require('json-parser')`, that is if `json-parser` is the name of the module.